# A tutorial in creating very basic simulations with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have recently been learning to programme in Javascript. I was told a while a go that it was possible to create 'simulations'. I am currently a university student studying physics and am particularly interested in making a very basic simulation that shows two (2D) balls being drawn to each other under the acts of gravity ( so basically a very simple simulator illustrating gravitational attraction - I was told this was particularly simple?)

However I have been searching various websites as well as emailing people from forums (despite getting no response). Is there a tutorial where I can learn to code this sort of thing (I would imagine  it involves introducing the idea of vectors). I am able to create the visual balls (using some basic html) and the actual Maths side is not a problem. The issue really lies in being able to draw all these things together.

Comment: Guys he's a physics student, he probably eats differentials and integrals for breakfast. He doesn't need a physics library, he needs a graphics library that's easy to get a handle on.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato just because he's a physics student doesn't mean he feels like hard-coding gravitational calculations. I'm an ex-physics major too, but that doesn't mean I feel like reinventing the wheel every time I throw a game or physics sim together

Comment: You could be totally right, but the question prompt does not seem that way. 

"I am able to create the visual balls (using some basic html) and the actual Maths side is not a problem. The issue really lies in being able to draw all these things together."

hopefully he'll come back around to clarify

Comment: @VoronoiPotato I guess you're right, in a way. But most physics libraries don't do all the math for you at all -- they just take care of the annoying stuff. I can say with a high level of confidence that in 2012, nobody wants to code up matrix/3d vector operations in plain ole javascript.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. I wonder where the hell he went though.

Comment: Hey guys! I have returned. Well it's difficult to clarify totally what i need, as i'm not even that sure myself. What i was trying to imply was that if i need to do linear algebra.. or mathematics that isn't a problem (though as pointed out by Philip i have been told by numerous people that you don't want to 're-invent' the wheel every time you sim). So presumably i need a physics library? Any guidance towards exactly what i need (perhaps a tutorial or something i can follow the code with so i can make sense of whats happening) would be great! thanks for the great/speedy responses!

Answer (score 0):

Basic physics simulators need at least:

- Position of object (x, y)
- Size/shape of object (usually through an image)
- Speed and direction of movement

Assuming then that gravity goes downwards, that's all you need: Just keep adding the gravity vector to the velocity of the object every step of simulation.

If you want to simulate space, however, where objects are attracted to each other, you need to know the mass of each object and calculate gravity for each object: For each object, look for all the other objects and calculate the force of gravity. Add all the resulting gravity vectors together, and add that to the current velocity to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into "[Processing.js](http://www.processingjs.org)" and yes gravitational attraction is fairly simple. The site that offers the library has a number of examples that might help you.

www.processingjs.org

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest learning a physics engine for javascript, like [**BOX2DJS**](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/). You could probably get away with any physics engine designed for games, as that's gonna be basically what you need. Usually there will be tutorials for any of those physics engines, and then doing what you want to do will become pretty easy for you.

Comment: ok great, i will take a look at that. Before i just in head first, what prerequisites would you say there are to being able to use this? thanks again!

Comment: @HarryRobinson if you have a fairly solid background in/understanding of javascript, you should be fine. Don't limit yourself to just Box2Djs though. I'd suggest searching around for game physics/drawing engines, and see which one seems to suit your needs best. I'd venture to say that almost any of them would work, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not sure i'd go as far as saying i have a solid background. I've done quite a few tutorials in javascript (mainly the ones on code academy) - just trying to branch out (while also integrating things i've learnt already i.e physics).

Comment: @HarryRobinson yeah, you should be good then! And if all else fails, familiarize yourself with `jQuery`, which comes packed with several functions for animating elements. You'd have to manually code out the physics side for that, but everything else would be fairly easy

Comment: Ok great, i was going to get into jQuery once i got to that point on the course, so should be coming up soon anyway! will fiddle around with that simulator for sure. Thanks for all the guidance Philip.

Comment: @HarryRobinson no problem. I won't beg for rep, but if it turns out that this answer is what got you on track, make sure to accept it :) <-- very hard to say that without it sounding like me begging for rep

Comment: sure thing - np. I'm pretty sure i already rated it. (the very first comment). If it appears i haven't please let me know. It was great direction and a fast response. I'm sure i'll have more in the near future!